# My OLED display just stays completely white

Tags: esp32, micropython

I am programming an ESP32 with Micropython and Thonny IDE.

I upload the following SSD1306 driver library:

---

```
#MicroPython SSD1306 OLED driver, I2C and SPI interfaces created by Adafruit

import time
import framebuf

# register definitions
SET_CONTRAST        = const(0x81)
SET_ENTIRE_ON       = const(0xa4)
SET_NORM_INV        = const(0xa6)
SET_DISP            = const(0xae)
SET_MEM_ADDR        = const(0x20)
SET_COL_ADDR        = const(0x21)
SET_PAGE_ADDR       = const(0x22)
SET_DISP_START_LINE = const(0x40)
SET_SEG_REMAP       = const(0xa0)
SET_MUX_RATIO       = const(0xa8)
SET_COM_OUT_DIR     = const(0xc0)
SET_DISP_OFFSET     = const(0xd3)
SET_COM_PIN_CFG     = const(0xda)
SET_DISP_CLK_DIV    = const(0xd5)
SET_PRECHARGE       = const(0xd9)
SET_VCOM_DESEL      = const(0xdb)
SET_CHARGE_PUMP     = const(0x8d)


class SSD1306:
    def __init__(self, width, height, external_vcc):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.external_vcc = external_vcc
        self.pages = self.height // 8
        # Note the subclass must initialize self.framebuf to a framebuffer.
        # This is necessary because the underlying data buffer is different
        # between I2C and SPI implementations (I2C needs an extra byte).
        self.poweron()
        self.init_display()

    def init_display(self):
        for cmd in (
            SET_DISP | 0x00, # off
            # address setting
            SET_MEM_ADDR, 0x00, # horizontal
            # resolution and layout
            SET_DISP_START_LINE | 0x00,
            SET_SEG_REMAP | 0x01, # column addr 127 mapped to SEG0
            SET_MUX_RATIO, self.height - 1,
            SET_COM_OUT_DIR | 0x08, # scan from COM[N] to COM0
            SET_DISP_OFFSET, 0x00,
            SET_COM_PIN_CFG, 0x02 if self.height == 32 else 0x12,
            # timing and driving scheme
            SET_DISP_CLK_DIV, 0x80,
            SET_PRECHARGE, 0x22 if self.external_vcc else 0xf1,
            SET_VCOM_DESEL, 0x30, # 0.83*Vcc
            # display
            SET_CONTRAST, 0xff, # maximum
            SET_ENTIRE_ON, # output follows RAM contents
            SET_NORM_INV, # not inverted
            # charge pump
            SET_CHARGE_PUMP, 0x10 if self.external_vcc else 0x14,
            SET_DISP | 0x01): # on
            self.write_cmd(cmd)
        self.fill(0)
        self.show()

    def poweroff(self):
        self.write_cmd(SET_DISP | 0x00)

    def contrast(self, contrast):
        self.write_cmd(SET_CONTRAST)
        self.write_cmd(contrast)

    def invert(self, invert):
        self.write_cmd(SET_NORM_INV | (invert & 1))

    def show(self):
        x0 = 0
        x1 = self.width - 1
        if self.width == 64:
            # displays with width of 64 pixels are shifted by 32
            x0 += 32
            x1 += 32
        self.write_cmd(SET_COL_ADDR)
        self.write_cmd(x0)
        self.write_cmd(x1)
        self.write_cmd(SET_PAGE_ADDR)
        self.write_cmd(0)
        self.write_cmd(self.pages - 1)
        self.write_framebuf()

    def fill(self, col):
        self.framebuf.fill(col)

    def pixel(self, x, y, col):
        self.framebuf.pixel(x, y, col)

    def scroll(self, dx, dy):
        self.framebuf.scroll(dx, dy)

    def text(self, string, x, y, col=1):
        self.framebuf.text(string, x, y, col)


class SSD1306_I2C(SSD1306):
    def __init__(self, width, height, i2c, addr=0x3c, external_vcc=False):
        self.i2c = i2c
        self.addr = addr
        self.temp = bytearray(2)
        # Add an extra byte to the data buffer to hold an I2C data/command byte
        # to use hardware-compatible I2C transactions.  A memoryview of the
        # buffer is used to mask this byte from the framebuffer operations
        # (without a major memory hit as memoryview doesn't copy to a separate
        # buffer).
        self.buffer = bytearray(((height // 8) * width) + 1)
        self.buffer[0] = 0x40  # Set first byte of data buffer to Co=0, D/C=1
        self.framebuf = framebuf.FrameBuffer1(memoryview(self.buffer)[1:], width, height)
        super().__init__(width, height, external_vcc)

    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.temp[0] = 0x80 # Co=1, D/C#=0
        self.temp[1] = cmd
        self.i2c.writeto(self.addr, self.temp)

    def write_framebuf(self):
        # Blast out the frame buffer using a single I2C transaction to support
        # hardware I2C interfaces.
        self.i2c.writeto(self.addr, self.buffer)

    def poweron(self):
        pass


class SSD1306_SPI(SSD1306):
    def __init__(self, width, height, spi, dc, res, cs, external_vcc=False):
        self.rate = 10 * 1024 * 1024
        dc.init(dc.OUT, value=0)
        res.init(res.OUT, value=0)
        cs.init(cs.OUT, value=1)
        self.spi = spi
        self.dc = dc
        self.res = res
        self.cs = cs
        self.buffer = bytearray((height // 8) * width)
        self.framebuf = framebuf.FrameBuffer1(self.buffer, width, height)
        super().__init__(width, height, external_vcc)

    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.spi.init(baudrate=self.rate, polarity=0, phase=0)
        self.cs.high()
        self.dc.low()
        self.cs.low()
        self.spi.write(bytearray([cmd]))
        self.cs.high()

    def write_framebuf(self):
        self.spi.init(baudrate=self.rate, polarity=0, phase=0)
        self.cs.high()
        self.dc.high()
        self.cs.low()
        self.spi.write(self.buffer)
        self.cs.high()

    def poweron(self):
        self.res.high()
        time.sleep_ms(1)
        self.res.low()
        time.sleep_ms(10)
        self.res.high()
```

---

And the following code:

---

```
# Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com

from machine import Pin, SoftI2C
import ssd1306
from time import sleep

# ESP32 Pin assignment 
i2c = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21))

oled_width = 128
oled_height = 64
oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(oled_width, oled_height, i2c)

oled.text('Hello, World 1!', 0, 0)
oled.text('Hello, World 2!', 0, 10)
oled.text('Hello, World 3!', 0, 20)
        
oled.show()
```

---

But my OLED display just stays full white, with random pixels.

[Display full white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6RAZ.jpg)

Obs: I am using a 1.3" 128x64 OLED display bought in Aliexpress

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihzIE.png)

Comment: What you bought from Aliexpress might not be SSD1306 display, it could be SH1106-based display. All looks the same. If you do a I2C scan, if the address is 0x3c, it is SSD1306. If you get 0x78 or 0x7A, then you have a SH-1106 display.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue using 128x64 (SSD1306), with 0.96 inch and 1.54 inch displays.
My first 128x32 (0.96 inch) display works without problem.
I use micropython integrated ssd1306 module.
As hcheung mention above it could be sh1106. Even without answering to different i2c address.
I give it a try:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
import sh1106

# ESP32 Pin assignment 
i2c = I2C(0, scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(23))

display = sh1106.SH1106_I2C(128, 64, i2c, None, 0x3c)
display.sleep(False)
display.fill(0)
display.text('Testing 1', 0, 0, 1)
display.show()
```

and it worked for both of the display. Guess cheap Aliexpress displays can be that way :) . You can download library from: [here](https://github.com/scy/SH1106)

Answer (score 0):

The display that you have looks just like the two displays that I have been working with on my Raspberry Pi. Most of the 1.3 inch 128x64 are sh1106 displays. Github has a driver for them. https://github.com/robert-hh/SH1106

I have my displays working on my Pi with Python. I will post my code as it may help you on your ESP32.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Program to Test and display date, time, month, day and year

"""
Tested only on (HiLetgo 1.3" IIC I2C Serial 128x64 SSH1106 SSD1306
  OLED LCD Display LCD Module for Arduino AVR PIC STM32), (Walfront 1.3
  Inch 128X64 IIC I2C SPI Serial OLED Display Module White Text Color
  for MP3 Function Cellphone Smart Health Device) and the
  (Raspberry Pi 4B 32bit). These displays only has page mode.

PREREQ:
  The i2c display connected to i2c GPIO pins, 3.3v & gnd.
  The /boot/config.txt has: dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=400000
  The shell command  ls -l /dev/i2c*, shows /dev/i2c-1.
  The shell command  i2cdetect -y 1, shows the device address.
  
NOTE:
  The i2c display device does not have a reset, so registers and 
  display memory may be in any state (garbage on the display).

This program will put the device in a known state.
  Set display on, ram on, normal and page mode.
  Run some test, clear ram and turn display off (sleep).
  Adjust varibles and program to your needs.

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/
https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1813/SH1106.pdf
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/e/e3/1.3inch-SH1106-OLED.pdf
https://www.electronicwings.com/sensors-modules/ssd1306-oled-display
https://docs.kernel.org/i2c/smbus-protocol.html
https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/2047793/0/0/1/ssd1306.html

"""

#import os
#os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
from smbus import SMBus
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
#import pygame

### I2C usage ###

bus = SMBus(1)  # Create a new I2C bus
addr = 0x3C  # Address of i2c device (128x64) 
wth, hgh = 132, 64  # My sh1106 device memory is 132x64.
reg = 0x00  # Write to registers w/wo data
mem = 0x40  # Write to display memory

### Commands ###

DspClk    = 0xD5  # Display Clock (needs 1 data)
ClkData   = 0x80  # (default 80)
MuxRatio  = 0xA8  # Multiplex Ratio  (needs 1 data)
RatioData = 0x3F  # (0x3F default)
DspSlp    = 0xAE  # Display off (sleep)
DspOn     = 0xAF  # Display on
DspCts    = 0x81  # Contrast (needs 1 data)
CtsData   = 0x30  # (0x7F default) Adjust to your needs.
DspRamOff = 0xA5  # Entire display on, ignore ram
DspRamOn  = 0xA4  # Display on, ram on
DspInv    = 0xA7  # Display inverted
DspNor    = 0xA6  # Display normal
ColStartL = 0x00  # Column start address lower nibble For Page
ColStartH = 0x10  # Column start address upper nibble For Page
MemAddrMd = 0x20  # Memory address mode (needs 1 of 3 data) *1
PageData  = 0x02  # Page Addressing Mode (0x02 default) *1
RamStart  = 0x40  # Ram display start
SegMap    = 0xA0  # Segment remap
Pg0       = 0xB0  # Start page For Page (B0 - B7)
ComNor    = 0xC0  # Set COM Output Scan Direction (default)
ComRev    = 0xC8  # Set COM Output Scan Direction (remapped)
DspOfSet  = 0xD3  # Set Display Offset (needs 1 data)
OfSetData = 0     # (0 default)
# *1 not needed for sh1106 displays

### Setup ###

def wrcmd(cmd):
    bus.write_byte_data(addr, reg, cmd)

def wrram(data):
    bus.write_byte_data(addr, mem, data)

def dsploc(col_start=0, pg=0):  # Display Column Start and Page location
    col_start += 2              # memory = 132 bits, display = 128 pixels
    ColStartL = col_start % 16
    ColStartH = col_start // 16 + 0x10
    for cmd in [(Pg0 + pg), ColStartL, ColStartH]:
        wrcmd(cmd)

def clrmem():
    dsploc()
    for x in range(hgh // 8):
        wrcmd(Pg0 + x)
        for y in range(wth):
            wrram(0x00)

def setup():
    for cmd in [DspClk, ClkData, MuxRatio, RatioData, DspOfSet, OfSetData,
                DspOn, DspCts, CtsData, DspRamOn, DspNor, MemAddrMd,
                PageData, RamStart, SegMap]:  # *1 MemAddrMd, PageData
        wrcmd(cmd)                            # not needed for sh1106.
    clrmem()


def Test():
    for w in (0xFF, 0x49):
        for x in range(hgh // 8):
            wrcmd(Pg0 + x)
            for y in range(wth):
                wrram(w)
                sleep(.003)

setup()
#Test(); clrmem()  # Uncommit to run Test
#exit()  # Uncommit to exit after Test

### Fonts ###

BA = ((0x80,0xE0,0xF0,0x78,0x3C,0x1E,15,0x1E,0x3C,0x78,0xF0,0xE0,0x80,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

BD = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,0x1E,0x3E,0xFC,0xF8,0xE0,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,7,3,1,0,0))

BF = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

BJ = ((15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,0),
      (0xE0,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0),
      (1,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0,0,0))

BM = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0,0xC0,0xF0,0x3C,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,3,15,3,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

BN = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,3,15,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,15,15,15,0))

BO = ((0xE0,0xF8,0xFC,0x3E,0x1E,15,15,15,0x1E,0x3E,0xFC,0xF8,0xE0,0),
      (0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (0,1,3,7,7,15,15,15,7,7,3,1,0,0))

BS = ((0xF0,0xFC,0xFE,0x9F,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF0,0),
      (15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

BT = ((15,15,15,15,15,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0))

BW = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC0,0xF0,0x3C,15,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,15,15,15,0))

Ma = ((0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0),
      (0,0xFC,0xFF,0xFF,0xE7,0xE3,0xE3,0xE7,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mb = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,3,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,7,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

Mc = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0),
      (0,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0x87,3,3,3,3,3,0x87,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,0))

Md = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0x87,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,15,15,15,7,15,15,0))

Me = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x33,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x3F,0x3F,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,14,14,14,14,14,7,0))

Mg = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0),
      (0,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0x30,0x70,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,0))

Mh = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,7,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mi = ((0,0,0,0,0x1E,0x1E,0x1E,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0))

Ml = ((0,0,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,7,15,15,15,15,0,0,0))

Mn = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,7,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mo = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,3,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

Mp = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (0,0x7F,0x7F,0x7F,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))

Mr = ((0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x0F,0x07,0x07,0x07,0x0F,0),
      (0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0))

Mt = ((0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,7,15,15,15,15,15,0,0))

Mu = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,7,0))

Mv = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,7,0x3F,0xFF,0xFC,0xC0,0xC0,0xFC,0xFF,0x3F,7,0),
      (0,0,0,0,3,15,15,3,0,0,0,0))

My = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,7,0x3F,0xFF,0xFC,0xC0,0xC0,0xFC,0xFF,0x3F,7,0),
      (0,0x70,0x70,0x70,0x71,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,1,0,0,0))

D0 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x1F,15,15,15,15,0x1F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x80,0,0x7,0x7,0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D1 = ((0,0,0,0x18,0x1C,0x1E,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0))

D2 = ((0,0x1E,0x1E,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x1E,0xFE,0xFC,0xF8,0),
      (0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xF0,0x78,0x3C,0x1E,15,7,3,1,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0))

D3 = ((0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF8,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xF9,0xF9,0xF0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,1,0))

D4 = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,14,14,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0))

D5 = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

D6 = ((0,0xF0,0xFC,0xFE,0x1F,15,15,15,15,15,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x8F,7,7,7,7,0x8F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D7 = ((0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3F,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xF0,0xFC,0x3F,15,0x03,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,12,15,15,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

D8 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x9F,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,0xF0,0xF9,0xFF,0x8F,7,7,7,7,0x8F,0xFF,0xF9,0xF0,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D9 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x1F,15,15,15,15,0x1F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,14,14,14,14,0x8F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

sp = ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))  # space

cl = ((0,0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0,0),  # colon
      (0,0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

cm = ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),              # comma + space
      (0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0x67,0x77,0x7F,0x3F,0,0,0,0,0))

t0 = ((0,0x84,0xC6,0xE6,0xB6,0x9E,0x8C,0),  # 20 vertical stacked
      (0,0xE1,0xF1,0x31,0x31,0xF1,0xE1,0),
      (0,3,7,6,6,7,3,0))

t1 = ((0,0x84,0xC6,0xE6,0xB6,0x9E,0x8C,0),  # 21 vertical stacked
      (0,1,0x21,0xF1,0xF1,1,1,0),
      (0,0,6,7,7,6,0,0))

wk = ((BS,Mu,Mn), (BM,Mo,Mn), (BT,Mu,Me), (BW,Me,Md),   # week days
      (BT,Mh,Mu), (BF,Mr,Mi), (BS,Ma,Mt))

num = (D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9)                   # numbers

mth = ((),(BJ,Ma,Mn),(BF,Me,Mb),(BM,Ma,Mr),(BA,Mp,Mr),  # months
       (BM,Ma,My),(BJ,Mu,Mn),(BJ,Mu,Ml),(BA,Mu,Mg),
       (BS,Me,Mp),(BO,Mc,Mt),(BN,Mo,Mv),(BD,Me,Mc))

### Propgram to display time and date  ###
###   on an i2c display.               ###

def gtdttm():  # GeT DaTe and TiMe
    fdttm = datetime.now()
    dttm = fdttm.strftime("%w %m %b %d %Y %a %I:%M")
    return dttm.split()

def rnfnt(fnt, lngh, start, pg=0):  # ReNder 1 FoNT
    for x in range(3):              # Fonts use 3 pages per charature.
        dsploc(start, x + pg)       # Set start and page per character.
        for y in range(lngh):
            z = fnt[x][y]
            wrram(z)

def sufnt(fntts, ix, dom=None):  # SetUp FoNT TypeS, IndeX, Day Or Month
    fix = dttm[ix]               # Field of DaTe TiMe by IndeX
    arfnts = []; arlnghs = []     # Font list, font lenght list
    for w in range(len(fntts)):  # Set font type to font.
        if dom: fnt = dom[int(fix)][w]  # Alph only charatures
        elif fntts[w] == "D": fnt = num[int(fix[w])]
        elif fntts[w] == ":": fnt = cl
        elif fntts[w] == ",": fnt = cm
        elif fntts[w] == "t": fnt = t0 if fix[w] == "0" else t1
        arfnts.append(fnt)
        arlnghs.append(len(fnt[0]))
    return arfnts, arlnghs

def dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg):  # DiSPlay selected Alp-Num charatures
    for w in range(len(lnghs)):
            fnt = fnts[w]
            rnfnt(fnt, lnghs[w], start, pg)
            start += lnghs[w] + 1

def blink(off):  # blink the colon
    start = 78; pg = 0
    if off == True: fnt = (cl); blk = True  # if off display colon
    else: fnt = (sp); blk = False           # else display space
    rnfnt(fnt, len(cl[0]), start, pg)
    return blk

### main ###
            
svdttm = []         # SaVe DaTe and TiMe
for x in range(8):  # Save area for Date and Time
    svdttm.append(" ")
#print(gtdttm())
wd = 0; mn = 1; dy = 3; yr = 4; ct = 6  # index dttm, WeekDay, MoNth#,...
blk = False  # BLinK = off

### Loop starts here ###

while True:

    dttm = gtdttm()  # DaTe & TiMe; wk#,mth#,month,day,year,weekday,H:M
    
    if dttm[wd] != svdttm[wd]:  # Day of the Week; 0:Sunday, 1:Monday
        start = 0; pg = 0
        fntts = ("B", "M", "M")  # FoNT TypeS, Big & Medium size
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, wd, wk)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[wd] = dttm[wd]

    if dttm[ct] != svdttm[ct]:  # Current Time; hour:minute
        start = 48; pg = 0
        fntts = ("D", "D", ":", "D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, ct)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        blk = True
        svdttm[ct] = dttm[ct]
    elif blk == True: blk = blink(False)
    else: blk = blink(True)

    if dttm[mn] != svdttm[mn]:  # Month Number; 1:January
        start = 0; pg = 4
        fntts = ("B", "M", "M")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, mn, mth)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[mn] = dttm[mn]

    if dttm[dy] != svdttm[dy]:  # DaY of the month
        start = 48; pg = 4
        fntts = ("D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, dy)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[dy] = dttm[dy]

    if dttm[yr] != svdttm[yr]:
        start = 78; pg = 4
        fntts = (",", "t", "D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, yr)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[yr] = dttm[yr]

    sleep(1)  # Sleep a second before update(s) and blink the colon.
```